# prevent emacs deleting ")"

Tags: balanced-parentheses, smartparens, parentheses

I don't want to turn off entire smartparens or similar mode

```
((([cursor]))
```

When I type `)` at cursor location I expect it to be

```
((()))
```

but it becomes

```
((())
```

How to find out which mode is causing it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the description, it looks like `elec-pair` behavior with user option `electric-pair-skip-self` set to `t`.

Firstly, check if `electric-pair-mode` is enabled. Simply calling `M-x electric-pair-mode` --which toggles the mode-- should be enough for a quick test.

If the mode is enabled, setting `electric-pair-skip-self` to `nil` or `#'electric-pair-default-skip-self` (default value) will change the behavior to either never omitting a paren or omitting it in accordance with another user option: `electric-pair-preserve-balance` (start with the default value of `t`, it should work fine).

Comment: Thank you. but it's not turned on. I guess some other mode is doing it..